# Download OroElasticSearchBundle

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I've checked the bundle documentation available here => https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/bundles/platform/ElasticSearchBundle/#bundle-docs-platform-elastic-search-bundle

But I was not able to found the bundle code anywhere in vendor and git repo's. Is it removed or available anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic Search is supported only in the Enterprise Edition of OroCommerce & OroCRM.

For more details, see the documentation: [Community vs Enterprise Edition](https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/getting-started/community-vs-enterprise/).